# Slow Litespeed container in docker

Tags: docker, performance, localhost, litespeed, openlitespeed

I installed on my computer ols-docker-env container in docker for developing wordpress/woocommerce sites on localhost. Everything works fine, but there is one problem - when I reload page it takes about 5-10 second or longer. Sometimes it's throwing 503 error.

I've tried to change memory_limit in php.ini for 12G, but it didn't help.

Earlier I was using XAMPP and it was much faster.